# Can someone check my answer to this integral using partial fractions?

Tags: calculus, integration

The problem is $\int \frac{x^2}{x^4-6x^2-27} dx$. I got the answer $\frac{1}{8}\ln |\frac{x-3}{x+3}|+\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\arctan\frac{x}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+C$  which seems correct to me but apparently I am getting this wrong, but I cannot seem to figure out where.  Any help is appreciated.  Below is a picture of my work:

[image]

Comment: [Looks correct](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+x%5E2%2F(x%5E4-6x%5E2-27)). What answer were you expecting? Where was this answer coming from? (Many textbooks have errors in their answers.)

Comment: Thanks, this is from a problem through WebAssign (online Calculus 2 class).  I guess the system is just grading incorrectly?  I don't have an answer to go off of because it randomizes the numbers for each problem.

Comment: It may be the case that it was expecting a different form of the answer, but since we don't know what the answer is, we can't help you too much.

Comment: Directly differentiating the proposed antiderivative gives the correct integrand.  So the only thing I can think of, other than an error,  is the book has a different form that ends up differing by a constant, like both $x^2-x$ and $(2x-1)^2/4$ being correct antiderivatives of $2x-1$.

Comment: Are there any domain restrictions? Maybe the webassign form expects the argument of the logarithm to be positive, leading to $\log\frac{3-x}{x+3}$ or  $\log\frac{x-3}{x+3}$ depending.